# apt wants to uninstall VLC because libgles1 is too old, even though the VLC team removed the libgles1 dependency

Tags: apt, ppa, vlc

From `/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log`:

```
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
Investigating (0) libgles1-mesa [ amd64 ] < 12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 > ( libs )
Broken libgles1-mesa:amd64 Depends on libglapi-mesa [ amd64 ] < 12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 -> 17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 > ( libs ) (= 12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16   .04.1)
    Considering libglapi-mesa:amd64 64 as a solution to libgles1-mesa:amd64 2
    Removing libgles1-mesa:amd64 rather than change libglapi-mesa:amd64
Investigating (0) vlc [ amd64 ] < 2.2.2+git20170721+r59033+56~ubuntu16.04.1 > ( video )
Broken vlc:amd64 Depends on libgles1-mesa [ amd64 ] < 12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 > ( libs ) (>= 7.8.1)
    Considering libgles1-mesa:amd64 2 as a solution to vlc:amd64 1
Broken vlc:amd64 Depends on libgles1 [ amd64 ] < none ->  > ( none )
    Considering libgles1-mesa:amd64 2 as a solution to vlc:amd64 1
    Or group remove for vlc:amd64
Done
```

Searching the web, I found that [libgles1 has been deprecated](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vlc/+bug/1676845).

The VLC team have updated their dependencies from 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.2, but my system has apparently not caught up with that (I checked by running `apt-cache depends vlc`, and it shows a dependency on libgles1-mesa).

Now it happens that a couple of months ago I added the [launchpad videolan PPA](http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu) (to get the latest, least buggy VLC).

That gave me VLC version 2.2.7 and fixed the VLC bug, and is what I have on my system today.  I know, because `vlc --version` tells me so.

`apt-cache policy vlc` says:

```
Installed: 2.2.2+git20170721+r59033+56~ubuntu16.04.1
Candidate: 2.2.2+git20170721+r59033+56~ubuntu16.04.1
Version table:
*** 2.2.2+git20170721+r59033+56~ubuntu16.04.1 500
    500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.3 500
    500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
    500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages
 2.2.2-5 500
    500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
```

(It seems weird that `apt-cache policy` says that 2.2.2+git20170721+r59033+56~ubuntu16.04.1 is installed; I read that as vlc version 2.2.2, which conflicts with the 2.2.7 that `vlc --version` gives.)

Apparently I have Ubuntu version 16.04.2 LTS 64-bit installed (from System Details in the GUI Control Panel thing).

I suppose that I could disable the launchpad PPA, but in that case I would presumably revert to an older vlc binary which was crashing my system.

So my question is (at least I think this is the right question):
How do I convince apt that it's ok that libgles1-mesa is old or missing?

Comment: I'd `ppapurge` the vlc ppa, `sudo apt purge` vlc and libgles1-mesa to get to a consistent state. You can `apt download` vlc and install with `sudo dpkg -i --force-depends <package>` and see if it works. Probably the packager needs to update the required packages list?

Comment: I concur but there's something wrong with your system an/or with the VLC version you may have installed before. VLC from the 16.04 repositories installs and works, always.

Comment: You have not described any problem, just pasted some log chunks whose relevance is not clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was to fake a newer version of libgles1 using dpkg-deb. This is safe since that package is redundant on my system.

```
sudo ppa-purge -o  videolan -p stable-daily -d xenial
```

Now the newer vlc (2.2.7) is gone, and standard (crashy) vlc is back:

```
$ vlc --version
VLC media player 2.2.2 Weatherwax (revision 2.2.2-0-g6259d80)
```

Run `sudo apt remove libgles1-mesa`, so that Software Updater isn't bunged up any more.

Software Updater now installs libgles2 v17.0.7 plus various other related libs.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily
sudo apt update
```

Now `apt list --upgradeable` shows

```
libvlc5/xenial 2.2.2+git20170721+r59033+56~ubuntu16.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.3]
libvlccore8/xenial 2.2.2+git20170721+r59033+56~ubuntu16.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.3]
vlc/xenial 2.2.2+git20170721+r59033+56~ubuntu16.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.3]
vlc-data/xenial,xenial 2.2.2+git20170721+r59033+56~ubuntu16.04.1 all [upgradable from: 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.3]
vlc-nox/xenial 2.2.2+git20170721+r59033+56~ubuntu16.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.3]
vlc-plugin-notify/xenial 2.2.2+git20170721+r59033+56~ubuntu16.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.3]
vlc-plugin-samba/xenial 2.2.2+git20170721+r59033+56~ubuntu16.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.3]
```

Run Software Updater. It installs 5 of the 7 debs:

```
Start-Date: 2017-07-28  12:22:38
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.208'
Upgrade: vlc-plugin-samba:amd64 (2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.3, 2.2.2+git20170721+r59033+56~ubuntu16.04.1), vlc-plugin-notify:amd64    (2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.3, 2.2.2+git20170721+r59033+56~ubuntu16.04.1), libvlc5:amd64 (2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.3, 2.2.2+git201707   21+r59033+56~ubuntu16.04.1), libvlccore8:amd64 (2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.3, 2.2.2+git20170721+r59033+56~ubuntu16.04.1), vlc-data   :amd64 (2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.3, 2.2.2+git20170721+r59033+56~ubuntu16.04.1)
End-Date: 2017-07-28  12:22:42
```

Now run

```
sudo apt download libgles1-mesa
sudo dpkg-deb -x ~/libgles1-mesa_12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb .
sudo dpkg-deb --control ~/libgles1-mesa_12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb .
```

Modify the DEBIAN/control Depends line to read:

```
Depends: libglapi-mesa (= 17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libc6 (>= 2.2.5)
```

(because libglapi was upgraded to 17.0.7)

```
sudo dpkg-deb -b . ~/libgles1-mesa_17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libgles1-mesa_17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install vlc-nox
sudo apt install vlc
```

Now `vlc --version` outputs

```
VLC media player 2.2.7 Umbrella (revision 2.2.2+git20170721+r59033+56~ubuntu16.04.1)
```

Software Updater runs happily. Well I never!

Comment: Using 16.04.1 I ran in the following problems: 1) file 'control' is saved in the ``user`` folder, but it is expected inside a 'DEBIAN' folder, and 2) my ``user`` folder ended up owned by ``root`` -- I solved everything by changing the first two 'dpkg-deb' commands to use a (new) directory instead of ``.``. To build the deb, I did ``cd`` into the created directory and ran the 'dpkg-deb -b' command as indicated. And I had to move the ``control`` file into a new ``DEBIAN`` subfolder for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem when I upgraded to 16.04.2. The nightly builds don't seem to agree with it. So, I had to revert to what was available on the Universe repository.

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:videolan/master-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

That fixed it. Synaptic reports the nightly-build as broken now, if I re-add the ppa:videolan/master-daily.